# Why is the type of my new column integer instead of float?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Original Dataset image]

I'm trying to make a new column `event_t` by the code below.

```
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
    df['event_t'][i] = df['time'][i+1] - df['time'][i]
type(df['event_t'][0]) #int64
```

As you can see in the image, the type of the column `df['time']` is float64.
But when implementing the code above, my new column `'event_t'` becomes integer.
How can I make my column be calculated as float, so that the decimals are alive?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're going to want to read how to create a [mre] and then [edit] the question to include a very small sample of your dataframe so that we can test your results and try to come up with a solution. You should also avoid including images and instead format dataframe output as code. You can also take the [tour] and read [ask] for more help writing questions.

Comment: `df['event_t'][i] = ...` would fail unless you already created an `event_t` column earlier. The dtype is determined at that earlier point you haven't shown us. Trying to assign floats into that column won't change the dtype.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
df['event_t'] = df.time.shift(-1)
df.event_t = df.event_t -df.time
```

Solution df:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
out = []
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
    out.append(df['time'][i+1] - df['time'][i])
out.append(0)
df['event_t'] = out
```

I do not know your problem exactly. Specifically, how was the df['event_t'] generated? I need more information about your problem. Meanwhile you can try the above code which uses a list to gather the new column data and then assign that on a df column.

Comment: Please **answer** OP's question "why?".

Comment: The code is not complete to regenerate the situation.

Comment: The point is that if you provide solution then it means you understand the problem. Please explain what was wrong or what exactly you fixed.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like python is making integer-subtraction and making the result an integer. Python has the limitations for floating point sometimes. Python uses IEEE 754 doubles for its floats. I believe you have some out-of-range number beyond IEEE 754 doubles in your `df`, or you defined `df['event_t']` incorrectly before.

You can import `decimal` package.

```
from decimal import Decimal
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
    df['event_t'][i] = Decimal(df['time'][i+1]) - Decimal(df['time'][i])
```